# How to get old version of project code base from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

My current project vesrion is 1.52, but got issue in 1.48 version, need that codebase(1.48) from jenkins because in github we have only master branch no other brancehs. Any possible way to get it from jenkins. Thanking you advancly.

Comment: If the code is in GitHub, you should be able to find old versions of your code there even though you only have the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codebase is still in the GitHub repo, **unless** you rewrote the history with a git rebase + git pushed force on the master branch.

That said, the best thing you can do is to locate the commit on which your project version 1.48 is based, review if you have tags and releases in your GitHub repo, that will be the ideal scenario, to just checkout your repo to the release tag to get the desired code version (otherwise look for the commit messages).

In regards looking for the code base in Jenkins, I won't count with that option too much,  aside of  being way more complicated in comparison with the git repo inspection, it depends mainly of the job configuration setup:

- How is the Log Rotation Strategy configured by means of days to keep
  builds and Max # of builds to keep.
- If you keep or delete the workspace.
- If the build was run on the master itself or in a slave.
- If you saved not only the artifacts but also the git repo outside the
  workspace with the post build action archive artifacts...

You can either browse the workspace of the node where the build for the release 1.48 was made if it still exists, or look inside the builds folder for the archived artifacts inside '**$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/YOURJOB/builds**'